# How to call my jQuery function onload to close all divs a jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery functionality to open and close div on click that is working perfectly but i want to load the close functionality on load .That is not working here is my code..

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>jQuery Collapsible Demo</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/github.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- /CSS -->
  <style>       
    .circle {
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    #circle2 {
        width: 25px;
        height: 20px;
        background: #1998D7;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
      to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes spin {
      from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
      to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

    @-ms-keyframes spin {
      from { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); }
      to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

    #advanced {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;

        background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(45px 45px 45deg, circle cover, yellow 0%, orange 100%, red 95%);
        background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(45px 45px, circle cover, yellow, orange);
        background-image: radial-gradient(45px 45px 45deg, circle cover, yellow 0%, orange 100%, red 95%);


        /* webkit chrome, safari, mobile */
          -webkit-animation-name: spin; 
          -webkit-animation-duration: 3s; /* 3 seconds */
          -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
          -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

          /* mozilla ff */
          -moz-animation-name: spin; 
          -moz-animation-duration: 3s; /* 3 seconds */
          -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
          -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

          /* microsoft ie */
          -ms-animation-name: spin; 
          -ms-animation-duration: 3s; /* 3 seconds */
          -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
          -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
    }

</style>
</head>

 <script>
function testOnLoad(){
 function closeAll() {
        $('.page_collapsible').collapsible('closeAll');
    }


     $('#closeAll').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        closeAll();

    });
}

</script>
 <body onload="testOnLoad();">

 <h1 align="center">DASHBOARD</h1>

 <!-- left column collapsible -->

 <!-- /left column collapsible -->

 <div id="content">

    <a href="#" id="closeAll" title="Close all">Open All</a> | <a href="#"    id="openAll" title="Open All">Close All</a>

    <!-- collapsible -->
    <div align="center">
    <div class="page_collapsible collapse-close" id="body-section1" >STPCODE NOT REGISTERED<span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="circle2" class="circle">10</div></div> 
    <div style="display: none;" class="container" >
      <div class="content">
           <p>
               stpcode list
           </p>

        </div>
    </div>
   <!-- end collapsible -->


     <!-- collapsible -->
    <div class="page_collapsible collapse-close" id="body-section1">TOTAL NUMBER OF REGISTERED USERS IN DRAFT MODE<span></span></div>
     <div style="display: none;" class="container">
         <div class="content">
           <p>
              REGISTERED USERS IN DRAFT MODE
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
     <!-- end collapsible -->
<!-- collapsible -->
   <div class="page_collapsible collapse-close" id="body-section1">TOTAL NUMBER OF REGISTERED USERS IN PAYMENT INITIATED MODE<span></span></div>
    <div style="display: none;" class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <p>
           REGISTERED USERS IN PAYMENT INITIATED  MODE
        </p>

    </div>
</div>
 <!-- collapsible -->
<div class="page_collapsible collapse-close" id="body-section1">TOTAL NUMBER OF REGISTERED USERS IN PAYMENT REJECTED MODE<span></span></div>
<div style="display: none;" class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <p>
           REGISTERED USERS IN PAYMENT REJECTED  MODE
        </p>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- end collapsible -->

 <!-- collapsible -->
<div class="page_collapsible collapse-close" id="body-section1">TOTAL NUMBER OF REGISTERED USERS IN DISAPPROVED MODE<span></span></div>
<div style="display: none;" class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <p>
           REGISTERED USERS IN DISAPPROVED  MODE
        </p>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- end collapsible -->
</div>
<!-- end collapsible -->


<!-- collapsible -->

<!-- end collapsible -->
</div>

 <!-- JS -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_003.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="highlight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_002.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {

    //syntax highlighter
    hljs.tabReplace = '    ';
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

    $.fn.slideFadeToggle = function(speed, easing, callback) {
        return this.animate({opacity: 'toggle', height: 'toggle'}, speed, easing, callback);
    };

    //collapsible management
    $('.collapsible').collapsible({
        defaultOpen: 'section1',
        cookieName: 'nav',
        speed: 'slow',
        animateOpen: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideUp with custom function
            elem.next().slideFadeToggle(opts.speed);
        },
        animateClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideDown with custom function
            elem.next().slideFadeToggle(opts.speed);
        },
        loadOpen: function (elem) { //replace the standard open state with custom function
            elem.next().show();
        },
        loadClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the close state with custom function
            elem.next().hide();
        }
    });
    $('.page_collapsible').collapsible({
        defaultOpen: 'body_section1',
        cookieName: 'body2',
        speed: 'slow',
        animateOpen: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideUp with custom function
            elem.next().slideFadeToggle(opts.speed);
        },
        animateClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the standard slideDown with custom function
            elem.next().slideFadeToggle(opts.speed);
        },
        loadOpen: function (elem) { //replace the standard open state with custom function
            elem.next().show();
        },
        loadClose: function (elem, opts) { //replace the close state with custom function
            elem.next().hide();
        }

    });

    //assign open/close all to functions
    function openAll() {
        $('.page_collapsible').collapsible('openAll');
    }
    function closeAll() {
        $('.page_collapsible').collapsible('closeAll');
    }

    //listen for close/open all
    $('#closeAll').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        closeAll();

    });
    $('#openAll').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        openAll();
    });

   });
</script>
<!-- /JS -->


</body></html>
```

can anyone help me how to call the close function onload

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){//code here})` OR `$(function(){//code here})` warp your code from these one

Comment: <script>
 function testOnLoad(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
  
  $('#closeAll').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            closeAll();

        });
  }
 }

</script> i am doing this

Comment: It might help if you created a **reduced** test case, preferably with a live example on jsbin or jsfiddle.

Comment: It's really hard to answer this without access to the relevant bits of the JS you load in your multiple `<script>` elements. A complete, reduced test case would be really helpful for debugging your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Actually... the script tag that defined your testOnload function is place outside of the head tag and the body tag... I don' think that is even allowed in html. So that script block is probably never executed.

Comment: Apologies for not noticing that < head > and < body > getting removed by the editor. But check the example code. One script tag is misplaced.

Comment: That won't make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Your testOnLoad() function executes just fine.
When the function is called you get ".collapsible" is not a function. Probably because the function is defined in one of the .js scripts
Try moving  tag contatining the function under the imported .js files.

You can either use your function and call it via  or use the script form "Viswanath D"

I also noticed that you have multiple declarations of CloseAll function.

Comment: Since the function is called `onload`, all those scripts will have been loaded by the time the function runs.

Comment: You are right. Still the testOnLoad executes just fine. Move closeAll and openAll out of the $(document).ready function. Then call closeAll on body load or just call closeAll at the end of $(document).ready function.